Parsing Excel files without Apache POI
I have some Excel files in my project which require the workbook to be opened and saved to trigger a formula refresh. I want to open the Excel files, trigger a formula refresh and then save them.
I know that Apache POI is the best solution to be used here, but since I'm working with GraalVM, adding third party libraries is not possible for me and trying to include them, gives me this error:

org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: TypeError: Access to host
class org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook is not allowed or
does not exist.

I have also tried Java Robot to mimic an open and save, but it doesn't work for me as whenever I try to save the Excel, I have to select a label for my file before saving or editing
Is there any way I can trigger a formula refresh and save my Excel file? I do not need to change the contents.

You would have to reimplement that functionality of Apache POI on your own.

There is no excel parser in standard java library.

You could write a csv parser quite easily if csv is an acceptable alternative.

You can try to find alternative Excel parsing libraries that maybe compatible with GraalVM. Don't ask for recommendations in [so], it is against the guidelines.

I know that there is no excel parser, but I did try to use normal file read and write and methods in hopes that it would trigger a formula refresh, but since excel files can't be read by normal file methods, I'm kind of stuck

Nothing will 'trigger a formula refresh'. You have to implement the logic of reading the Excel XML format, update data, evaluate the formulas, update the results and write them back in the Excel format. And nothing prevents you of reading the Excel files with code or using an XML parser. It may be complex, but not impossible.

there are users who have made POI work on GraalVM - eg https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59178299/using-apache-poi-with-graalvm-native-image-classcastexception-from-xmlbeans - also found others using google searching - the users who suggest writing your own zip and XML based code are underplaying just how hard this is for non-trivial use cases - there are other java libs that are simpler, eg https://github.com/dhatim/fastexcel and therefore possibly simpler to get working in GraalVM

This question is similar to: Parsing Excel file without Apache POI. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

First off, why does GraalVM not allow access to those classes? I bet there's a switch you can flip, or some other tricks,
The 'parsing' problem is two-fold:

Some Excel (MS Office) files you can parse easily, such as anything that has 4 letters and end in x or m or t, like .xlsx, .xlsm, .xlst. Those are XML based. (more details below).
The old MS Office file formats are binary, so there's much more work behind reading them, because you'd need most of the specifications.

So depending on your requirement, you can do it rather easily, or rather hard.
Details on the XML-based files:
The new MS Office file formats are always .zip files that contain mostly .xml based files. Usually there's a project description, in which files to find data, and in which to find metadata.
Just use 7zip or another willing decompression tool to unzip the .xlsx file.
You'll get to know the basics pretty quickly, and then easily can read the new Excel file format.
I myself am quite disappointed with most aspects of Apache POI. So I have actually implemented a really lightweight library to read (and write) data from .xls? files. It's about 10'000 times faster and needs far less resources, because I can target it better at aspects of the XML content that I need (in-memory zip file content management, ignoring formats, borders, embedded resources etc), while Apache POI relies heavily on other libraries (xmlbeans) that encompass and parse all attributes.
Then again, whether you parse the .xml files or use a parser is up to you...
